# SAS Columnlabels in Excel via library

Tags: sas, export, export-to-excel

Is it possible to output the column labels of a dataset via xlsx Libname?
I can use the label output via proc export and ods excel. But i seem to miss something with the libname statement...

```
%let useColumnlabels = false;

%macro ExportDatasetInFileExcel(
        paraDirectory /*string*/
        , paraFilename /*string*/
        , paraWorksheetName /*string*/
        , paraDataSetName /*string*/
        , paraUseColumnLabels = &useColumnlabels. /*string true false */
    );

    libname refFile xlsx "&paraDirectory./&paraFilename..&outputFileExtensionExcel.";

    %if &paraUseColumnLabels. = true %then %do;
        data refFile.&paraWorksheetName.
                (DBLABEL = yes)
            ;
            set &paraDataSetName.;
        run;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        data refFile.&paraWorksheetName.;
            set &paraDataSetName.;
        run;
    %end;

    libname refFile clear;
%mend ExportDatasetInFileExcel;


data Example_DataSet_Labels;
  set sashelp.class;
  label name="Very  very very very very very long name of a very very very long string";
run;

%ExportDatasetInFileExcel(
    /home/sasserver/mypath
    , Filename
    , Workbook
    , Example_DataSet_Labels
    , paraUseColumnLabels = true
);
```

I tried the code above but got the following error

```
22: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.
NOTE 242-205: NOSPOOL is on. Rerunning with OPTION SPOOL might allow recovery of the LINE and COLUMN where the error has occurred.
ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name DBLABEL.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
```

Comment: i tried to follow the  [SAS Docu Viya](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_036/acpcref/p0rptbtkast6len1uzzxwj56vwhk.htm). and  [SAS Docu SAS9.4](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acreldb/p1aksmchxr4bekn1bdxjk4isnvna.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, *It is impossible*.

A native SAS dataset includes meta data, like the label and the `DBlabel` option.

A sheet or range in Excel does not have that, hence can never have labels, nor the `DBlabel` option.

Answer (score 0):

The `XLSX` library engine does not support labels, formats, etc. The engine is a data engine and you only get column name and data values. Use `ODS EXCEL` or `EXPORT` for a better Excel output experience.

However.....

You can coerce the engine to go beyond normal expectations.

Flex your SAS muscles by using `VALIDVARANY` and rename each SAS column to be a `=VLOOKUP(...)` formula and have the lookup values be the labels in a second sheet in the workbook!

Example:

Lab experiment #626, do not release.

```
data have;
  set sashelp.class;
  label name = 'The name used to refer to the person in the class.';
run;

proc contents noprint data=have out=havec;
proc sort data=havec;
by varnum;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select cats(name,'="=VLOOKUP(',varnum,',labels!A:B,2)"N')
  into :rename_eqns separated by ' '
  from havec
  order by varnum
  ;
quit;

libname xlfile xlsx "c:/temp/flex.xlsx"

options validvarname = any;

data xlfile.want;
  set have(rename=(&rename_eqns));
run;

data xlfile.labels;
  set havec;
  if missing(label) then label=name;
  keep varnum label;
run;

libname xlfile clear;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i like your suggestion but i can't use that because of my overall process

Comment: The data engine only allows for 32-character names, so, in cases of short enough labels you can rename a column to it's label.  But you really should use the other Excel making techniques.